# Using OgProtectExe from tponguard

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Can anyone show me a simple example how this component is used.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application (the one you want to protect by embedding a CRC), drop an `OgProtectExe` component. Use the `Object Inspector` to add a handler for it's single event (`OnChecked`, if I remember correctly). The handler should contain something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.OgProtectExe1Checked(Sender: TObject; Status: TExeStatus);
begin
  if (Status <> exeSuccess) then // CRC changed
    // Handle modified executable
end;
```

Possible `TExeStatus` values are:

```
exeSuccess         - CRC is OK
exeSizeError       - File size has changed
exeIntegrityError  - CRC doesn't match
exeNotStamped      - Executable not stamped
```

Build your application as usual. Use `StampExe` (from the OnGuard `examples\Delphi` folder) to stamp your executable with the CRC (or write your own app that calls the `OgProExe` unit's `ProtectExe` function to stamp it).

`ProtectExe` takes two parameters - the full path and filename of the executable to protect, and a boolean that indicates whether or not it should remove it's special marker after protecting. You should pass `True` unless you want to have the ability to unprotect the executable afterwards.

```
uses
  OgProExe;

...
if ProtectExe(YourExeName, EraseMarker) then  // executable stamped
```